# How has the rate of photon arrival from stars been estimated and then confirmed?

Tags: photometry, photons

My understanding is that we can estimate the total energy emitted over a star’s entire spectrum and from that and the star’s measured spectrum estimate how many photons of a given wavelength we should receive at a given instrument per second.

My question is: How has this been estimated and then measured to validate the estimation method? Are there specific papers or texts that lay out a widely agreed-upon method?

Comment: What are you suggesting? That the energy of a photon isn't $h\nu$? All "exposure time calculators" do these calculations; and they work.

Comment: "My understanding is that we can estimate the total energy emitted over a star’s entire spectrum" This usually happens *after the star's output has been measured at many wavelengths*, not before. Until recently photomultiplier tubes were widely used in Astronomy and certainly at low light levels they were used in photon-counting mode, and in some niche applications avalanche photodiodes are still used to count photons. But experiments that call into question the relationship between the energy of a photon and it's wavelength or frequency are rare now as none have shown significant deviations..

Comment: from $E = h \nu$ or $hc/\lambda$

Comment: I didn’t mean to imply any doubts about the Planck equation. I’m literally wondering how astronomers have estimated then validated the photon flux arriving at Earth, in a particular band, from a specific star. Thanks for the pointer to “exposure time calculators”, a term I wasn’t familiar with. It looks like many of these are developed for specific instruments in order to assist PIs.  I want to learn about the general method/process astronomers follow to create and then validate and refine these ETCs— is there a good published guide to that?

Comment: I think it's the "...how astronomers have estimated then ***validated*** the photon flux arriving at Earth" that's throwing some of us off. What does "validate" mean here? Are you drawing a distinction between photon flux (number of photons per second per unit area on Earth in a given wavelength range) with spectral intensity (energy per second per unit area on Earth in a given wavelength range)? Some measurement techniques use intensity, others use photon counting, and except for some rare experiments nobody validates one with the other. Instead they're used interchangeably.